# Java -SQL query to extract data from two tables?

Tags: java, sql

```
Select concat(substr(T_data,1,9),'001     ') AS Test_Data from DB1.T1 ;

Select * from DB1.T2 WHERE Test_Data  = 'Test_Data';
```

I need to join the DB1.T1 and DB1.T2 based on Test_Data

Comment: What trouble are you having? Are you getting an error message? What does your Java code look like?

Answer (score 0):

Use an INNER JOIN (or, if you want nulls, an outer join)

```
Select t2.*
from DB1.T1 t1
INNER JOIN DB1.T2 t2 ON concat(substr(t1.T_data,1,9),'001     ') = t2.Test_Data
WHERE t2.Test_Data  = 'Test_Data';
```

Comment: I am getting issue in T2.Test_Data

Comment: Try it with t2.Test_Data. I fixed the capitalization.